# Using H2 Database File-Based in EKS for Job Metadata Sharing Between Pods

Tags: spring-batch, h2

I am working on an application deployed on Amazon EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service), and I have a requirement to use an H2 database for storing job-related metadata as the Spring batch does not have support for Cassandra. The H2 database will be file-based, and I need to share this database file between pods running in the EKS cluster.

My primary database is Cassandra, and I only intend to use the H2 database for job metadata storage. I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this in an EKS environment.

Here are some specific points I'm looking for help with:

```
File Storage Considerations:
Are there any specific considerations or best practices when using file-based databases in a Kubernetes environment, especially with regards to storage management?

H2 Database Configuration:
What configuration settings should I consider for the H2 database to ensure it works well in a multi-pod environment?

Isolation from Primary Cassandra Database:
As I am using Cassandra as my primary database, I want to ensure that the H2 database remains isolated and is only used for job-related metadata. Are there any recommended practices for achieving this?
```

Any insights, recommendations, or examples on configuring and managing file-based H2 databases in EKS for job metadata sharing would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!